# Indexing a concatenated foreign key field within SQL fact table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large Fact table (50m rows) consisting of 5 foreign keys and 5 value columns.

I have already created 5 dimension tables and indexed the foreign keys in the Fact table.   The performance has been great so far and querying the fact table using any of the dimensions is very quick.

There's been a slight change in requirements (table is being used for reporting) and now the user wants to be able to query the table using a concatenated field which consists of 2 of the dimension fields merged.

Here is a sample:

```
Dim1
Dim1key
Dim1Desc

Dim2
Dim2key
Dim2Desc

Fact_Data
Dim1key
Dim2key
Values1
values2
Values3
```

If I query the table using **dim1key = 5** or **dim2key = 10**,  it's very quick but I would now want to query the table using a merged dim1 & dim2 key,  eg **mergedkey = "5-10"** .    I tried querying the table using **concat_WS('-',Dim1key,Dim2key) = "5-10"**  but it's extremely slow and obviously doesn't leverage any of the indexes.

What's the best action for me to take here?   Should I add a merged column to my fact table using the above concat_ws function, then create a new dimension table cotaining the merged fields and then index the newly created merged column in the fact table?

...or am I over complicating this?      Just want to check fist as the indexing is very time consuming (stuck using the azure S1 Free trial DTU currently)

Thanks

Comment: That user requirement is ridiculous.  The user should just be able to query off of two independent fields.  Concatenating them seems arbitrary and prone to misuse.

Comment: Not obviously ridiculous.  Dimensional models are built for users, and should align to the business terminology.  For instance with cars "Model" and "Year" are could be modeled as dimensional attributes, but users think about them as a single dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a ludicrous requirement.  Lots of people use lots of highly dimensional fact tables without having to concatenate the keys as strings.

However, if you are forced to do such a thing, you can add a computed column to the fact table, persist it, and build an index:

```
alter table fact add merged_key as (concat_ws('-', Dim1key, Dim2key)) persisted;

create index idx_fact_merge on fact(merged_key);
```

This you can query the table as:

```
where merged_key = '5-10'
```

Comment: It is a silly requirement isn't it and i'm happy you said that as that's what I was thinking.  I'm quite new to this and even I thought so :-D    Thank you for your input and solution though, much appreciated